# глупо это задавать но не получается

Tags: python, python-3.x

На вход программе подается натуральное число `n \, (n \ge 2)n(n≥2)` – катет прямоугольного равнобедренного треугольника.

Напишите программу, которая выводит звездный треугольник в соответствии с примером.

Формат входных данных
На вход программе подается одно натуральное число `n \, (n \ge 2)n(n≥2)`

Формат выходных данных
Программа должна вывести треугольник в соответствии с условием задачи.

Sample Input 1:

3
Sample Output 1:

```
***
**
*
```

Sample Input 2:

11
Sample Output 2:

```
***********
**********
*********
********
*******
******
*****
****
***
**
*
```

```
n = int(input())
a = list(range(1,n+ 1)) + list(range(n-1,0,-1))
for i in a:
print('*'*i)
```

Comment: не получается я пробовал

Comment: в выводе ведь от большего к меньшему range(n,0,-1)

Comment: Test input:
3
Correct output:
***
**
*

Your code output:
*
**
***

Comment: Придумайте своему вопросу нормальный заголовок. А то действительно глупо.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
for i in range(int(input()), 0, -1):
    print("*" * i)
```

Answer (score 1):

Вот как-то так:

```
n = int(input())
while n > 0:
    print('*'*n)
    n -= 1
```

Comment: вайл пока юзать нельзя

Comment: Какие жесткие рамки )